# Exceptions not working as expected in PyQt5

Tags: python, excel, exception, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a form dialog in PyQt5. The objective of the program is to generate numbers according to a particular format depending on the Part type and store these numbers in an Excel sheet. The excel sheet is named 'Master Part Sheet.xlsx' and stored in the same directory as the script. The name of the excel sheet can be changed in the `workbookLayer` Class. The number of generated numbers is determined by the entry in the **number of part numbers required** field

The customer selected in the drop down menu also plays a role in generating a part number(only if it is a Machine Part). A number from 0-99 is stored in a dictionary against each customers name which is accessed while generating corresponding part numbers.

The input fields have to be checked when a user enters a value in them. Every time the value entered is incorrect(not in a certain range/ not in the specified format), an exception is called. The values are checked when the generate Qpushbutton in the form dialog is clicked.

The NTID field must be of the form UUUNUUU where U stands for upper case string and N stands for a Number. It is checked for with regular expressions and must otherwise throw exceptions.

The **machine number**  and **line number** fields must be in the range **0-99**, and must otherwise throw an exception prompting the user to check his/her entries in the message label.

After the entry of data by the user and these checks, the part numbers must be generated and written onto the excel sheet.

If the part type is a standard part, the part numbers are written onto the Standard parts sheet of the workbook. The max number of parts that can exist in this sheet are 10000. The part numbers must be unique.

If the sheet is a machine part, new sheets are created in the workbook where the part numbers are written onto. The sheets are created based on the  customer name the machine number and the line number. One sheet can have a maximum of 1000 parts and the numbers generated shouldn't be repeated in the sheet i.e they are unique.

Below is the code

```python
'''import all necessary libraries required for the project'''

import os
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import random
import time
import pickle
import re

class workbookLayer:

'''The constructor for the workbook object'''

    def __init__(self, source_file='Master Part Sheet.xlsx'): # Change source_file to get different sheet as source

        self.source_file = source_file
        self.part_type = None
        self.line_number = None
        self.machine_number = None
        self.customer_name = None
        self.ntid = None
        self.get_sheet_name()
    '''Get the path of the Excel workbook and load the workbook onto the object'''
    def get_sheet_name(self):

        self.file_path = os.path.realpath(self.source_file)
        self.wb = load_workbook(self.file_path)
        self.wb.get_sheet_names()
        return self.file_path, self.wb

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
        QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
        QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
        QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox)

import sys
'''The Pop up Box for addition of a new customer'''
class DialogCustomerAdd(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(DialogCustomerAdd, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        self.ok_button=QPushButton("OK")

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.ok_button)
        self.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.ok_button_action)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Add New Customer")

    def ok_button_action(self):

        global CUSTOMER_NAME
        global CUSTOMER_ID
        CUSTOMER_NAME = self.customer_name_text.text()
        CUSTOMER_ID = self.customer_id_text.text()
        self.close()

    def createFormGroupBox(self):

        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Customer Details")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.customer_name_label = QLabel("Name of the Customer")
        self.customer_name_text = QLineEdit()

        self.customer_id_label = QLabel("Enter Customer ID")
        self.customer_id_text = QLineEdit()

        layout.addRow(self.customer_name_label, self.customer_name_text)
        layout.addRow(self.customer_id_label, self.customer_id_text)

        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

'''The Pop up Box for deletion of an existing customer'''
class DialogCustomerDelete(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

   def __init__(self):
        super(DialogCustomerDelete, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        self.ok_button=QPushButton("OK")

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.ok_button)
        self.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.ok_button_action)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Delete Existing Customer")



    def ok_button_action(self):
        global POP_CUSTOMER
        POP_CUSTOMER = self.customer_delete_combobox.currentText()
        self.customer_delete_combobox.clear()
        self.close()


    def createFormGroupBox(self):

        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Customer Details")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.customer_name_label = QLabel(" Select the Customer to be deleted")
        self.customer_delete_combobox = QComboBox()
        self.customer_delete_combobox.addItems(CUSTOMER_LIST)

        layout.addRow(self.customer_name_label)
        layout.addRow(self.customer_delete_combobox)

        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

class DialogMain(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    wbl = workbookLayer() 

    def __init__(self):
        super(DialogMain, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        generate_button=QPushButton("Generate")
        generate_button.clicked.connect(self.generateNumbers)
        self.user_message_label = QLabel(" ")

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.user_message_label)
        mainLayout.addWidget(generate_button)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.add_new_customer_button)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.delete_customer_button)
        buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.closeIt)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)


        self.open_or_create_pickle_file()
        customer_name = [customer for customer,customer_id in self.customer_dict.items()]
        self.customer_name_combobox.addItems(customer_name)
        self.add_new_customer_button.clicked.connect(self.add_customer_window)
        self.delete_customer_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_customer_window)
        self.setWindowTitle("Part Number Generator ")
        global CUSTOMER_LIST
        CUSTOMER_LIST = customer_name

    def open_or_create_pickle_file(self): 
        self.customer_dict = dict()
        try:
            assert open("customer_diction.pickle","rb")
            pickle_in = open("customer_diction.pickle","rb")
            self.customer_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)
            pickle_in.close() 

        except FileNotFoundError:
            pickle_out = open("customer_dict.pickle","wb")

    def add_new_customer_to_pickle(self):
        global CUSTOMER_NAME
        global CUSTOMER_ID
        global CUSTOMER_LIST
        self.customer_name_combobox.addItem(CUSTOMER_NAME) 
        self.customer_dict[CUSTOMER_NAME] = CUSTOMER_ID
        customer_name = [customer for customer,customer_id in self.customer_dict.items()]
        CUSTOMER_LIST = customer_name
        pickle_out = open("customer_diction.pickle","wb")
        pickle.dump(self.customer_dict, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()

    def delete_customer_from_pickle(self):
        global POP_CUSTOMER
        del self.customer_dict[POP_CUSTOMER]
        customer_name = [customer for customer,customer_id in self.customer_dict.items()]
        global CUSTOMER_LIST
        CUSTOMER_LIST = customer_name
        self.customer_name_combobox.clear() 
        self.customer_name_combobox.addItems(customer_name)
        pickle_out = open("customer_diction.pickle","wb")
        pickle.dump(self.customer_dict, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()


    def add_customer_window(self):
        widget = DialogCustomerAdd()
        widget.exec_()

        self.add_new_customer_to_pickle()

    def delete_customer_window(self):
        widget = DialogCustomerDelete()
        widget.exec_()
        self.delete_customer_from_pickle()
        global POP_CUSTOMER
        self.user_message_label.setText('The customer ' + POP_CUSTOMER + ' has been deleted' )


    def closeIt(self): 
        self.close()

    def generateNumbers(self):

        self.wbl.line_number = self.line_number_text.text()
        self.wbl.machine_number = self.machine_number_text.text()
        self.wbl.customer_name =self.customer_name_combobox.currentText()
        self.wbl.part_type = self.part_type_combobox.currentText()
        self.wbl.ntid = self.ntid_text.text()  


        try:
            self.check_ntid()
        except AssertionError:
            self.user_message_label.setText('Please Enter User Details Correctly')

        try:
            if int(self.wbl.machine_number) > 99:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            self.user_message_label.setText('Please Enter machine number within 100')

        try:
            if int(self.wbl.line_number) > 99:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            self.user_message_label.setText('Please Enter Line number within 100')


        self.create_sheet_and_check_values()

        try:
            self.part_number_generator()
        except PermissionError:
            self.user_message_label.setText('Please Close the excel sheet before using this application')



    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Part Details")
        layout = QFormLayout()

        self.part_type_label = QLabel("Part Type:")
        self.part_type_combobox = QComboBox()
        self.part_type_combobox.addItems(['Standard Part', 'Machine Part'])

        self.customer_name_label = QLabel("Customer:")
        self.customer_name_combobox = QComboBox()
        self.add_new_customer_button = QPushButton("Add New Customer")
        self.delete_customer_button = QPushButton("Delete Existing Customer")

        self.ntid_label = QLabel("NTID of the User:")
        self.ntid_text = QLineEdit()

        self.machine_number_label = QLabel("Machine Number of the Part:")
        self.machine_number_text = QLineEdit()

        self.line_number_label = QLabel("Line Number of the Part:")
        self.line_number_text = QLineEdit()

        self.part_numbers_label = QLabel("Number of Part Numbers Required:")
        self.part_numbers_spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.part_numbers_spinbox.setRange(1, 999)

        layout.addRow(self.part_type_label, self.part_type_combobox)
        layout.addRow(self.customer_name_label, self.customer_name_combobox)

        layout.addRow(self.ntid_label, self.ntid_text)
        layout.addRow(self.machine_number_label, self.machine_number_text)
        layout.addRow(self.line_number_label, self.line_number_text)
        layout.addRow(self.part_numbers_label, self.part_numbers_spinbox)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)




    def  check_ntid(self):

            pattern = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]")
            assert pattern.match(self.wbl.ntid)


    def create_sheet_and_check_values(self):

        self.check_ntid()

        if self.wbl.part_type == 'Machine Part':
            self.prefix = int('3' +   self.customer_dict[self.wbl.customer_name] + self.wbl.line_number + self.wbl.machine_number)
            self.check_and_create_customer_sheet()
        else:
            self.prefix = 500000
            self.add_standard_parts_sheet()

        self.dest_filename = self.wbl.file_path


        self.ws1 = self.wbl.wb[self.wbl.sheet_name]
        self.random_numbers = self.part_numbers_spinbox.value()

        if (self.wbl.part_type == 'Machine Part'):
            try:
                assert self.random_numbers <  (1002 -(self.ws1.max_row))
            except AssertionError:
                self.user_message_label.setText('You have exceeded the range of allowable parts in the machine, you can get only {} more part numbers'.format(1001 -(self.ws1.max_row)))                
        else:
            try:
                assert self.random_numbers <  (10002 -(self.ws1.max_row))
            except AssertionError:
               self.user_message_label.setText('You have exceeded the range of allowable parts in this list, you can get only {} more part numbers'.format(10001 -(self.ws1.max_row)))

        '''This section of the method contains the logic for the generation of random number parts 
       according to the required format and also checks for clashes with already existing part numbers'''

    def part_number_generator(self):

        if (self.wbl.part_type == 'Machine Part'):
            part_numbers_list = random.sample(range( self.prefix*1000, self.prefix*1000 + 1000), self.random_numbers)
        else:
            part_numbers_list = random.sample(range( self.prefix*10000, self.prefix*10000 + 10000), self.random_numbers)


        first_column = set([(self.ws1[x][0].value) for x in range(2,self.ws1.max_row + 1 )])

        while True:
            additional_part_numbers_list = random.sample(range( self.prefix*1000, self.prefix*1000 + 1000), self.random_numbers - len (part_numbers_list))

            part_numbers_list = part_numbers_list + additional_part_numbers_list 

            part_numbers_list = list(set(part_numbers_list) - (first_column))

            if len(part_numbers_list) == self.random_numbers:
                break

        for row in range( self.ws1.max_row + 1, self.ws1.max_row + 1 + len(part_numbers_list)):
            '''write the generated part numbers onto the excel sheet corresponding to the customer'''

            self.ws1.cell(column = 1 , row = row, value = part_numbers_list.pop())
            self.ws1.cell(column = 3 , row = row, value = self.wbl.ntid)


        self.wbl.wb.save(self.wbl.file_path)

        self.user_message_label.setText(str(self.part_numbers_spinbox.value()) + " Part Numbers have been successfully generated. Please check the sheet " + self.wbl.sheet_name)


    def check_and_create_customer_sheet(self):
        self.wbl.sheet_name = '3' + self.customer_dict[self.wbl.customer_name] + self.wbl.line_number + self.wbl.machine_number +'xxx'
        if self.customer_not_exists():
            self.wbl.wb.create_sheet(self.wbl.sheet_name)
            self.wbl.wb.save(self.wbl.file_path)


        '''Check if the customer sheet exists'''        
    def customer_not_exists(self):
        sheet_name = '<Worksheet "'+ '3' +  self.customer_dict[self.wbl.customer_name] + self.wbl.line_number + self.wbl.machine_number +'xxx' + '">'
        return True if sheet_name not in str(list(self.wbl.wb)) else False


        '''Check if standard parts sheet exists. If not make a new sheet'''
    def add_standard_parts_sheet(self):
        sheet_name = '<Worksheet "'+ 'Standard Parts'+ '">'

        if sheet_name not in str(list(self.wbl.wb)):
            self.wbl.wb.create_sheet('Standard Parts')
            self.wbl.wb.save(self.wbl.file_path)

            self.wbl.sheet_name = 'Standard Parts'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = DialogMain()
sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

The `generateNumbers()` function in the `DialogMain()` Class  is called every time a 'generate' QpushButton is clicked in the QDialog layout. The program checks for correctness of the inputs and generates random numbers according to the required format in an excel sheet through openpyxl. The exceptions for the `self.wbl.ntid` and `PermissionError` work as expected. **However the exceptions for `self.wbl.machine_number` and `self.wb1.line_number` i.e for machine number inputs and line number inputs** in the dialog **seem to be ignored** and **the program executes even when the user entry is wrong**. Only the exception for NTID behaves as expected and the other exceptions fail to be raised even on wrong entry.

The dialog Box

[image]

I have added the entire code used to make it reproducible. Thanks

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I did try to follow it to my best. I felt the code is too long to be included here. Please suggest how I can improve my clarity. I am not very experienced at stack overflow. Thanks

Comment: The link explains everything very simply and clearly.

Comment: Ok. My bad. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything that stops your code from continuing after getting the wrong input. (Unless that's handled elsewhere.) Also, if you are only expecting integer values from all of those then you might be interested in using a QIntValidator (or QDoubleValdiator depending on if you want integers or floats in some cases.)

Comment: @ekhumoro I think I have adhered to the link you shared now. Could you be kind enough to help?

Comment: @AshishRaoM. That is certainly not a **minimal** example, and it cannot be **verified** without a specific xlxs file - so it is not **complete**. Also, you do not state what the correct inputs or outputs should be, nor how you expect the program to behave when it gets incorrect values.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have included the entire code as I do not know where the problem is and so that you could reproduce it. Half the code goes in setting up the dialog boxes in PyQt and I have commented these places. The xls file should be an xls file called 'Master Part Sheet.xls' which can be an empty file. The code should work as long as the file exists in the same directory as the script. I was perhaps fuzzy about the inputs and outputs earlier and have made it more elaborate on your suggestion.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you think the correct behaviour should be. What **specifically** should happen when an exception is raised? What **specific** part of the code do you think is not working properly? I think the real problem here is that you have not worked out in detail what you are trying to achieve. Take a close look at the `generateNumbers` method. Put lots of print statements in there (both inside and outside of the try/except blocks), and try to predict what the output should be. My hunch is that the output won't be what you imagine it should be.